# Verilog counting Module guidance

Tags: verilog, counting, vivado

I am trying to design a counting module in Verilog (or VHDL). It takes in an input byte and on every clock pulse it sequentially counts through only the '1s' in the byte.
for example:
if the input byte is: '00001111; then it counts and loops....
00000001, 00000010, 00000100, 00001000,
if the input byte is: '00000011; then it counts and loops....
00000001, 00000010,
if the input byte is: '01010101; then it counts and loops....
00000001, 00000100, 00010000, 01000000,

I have written this Verilog code.

```
module ripple_borrow ( req,    
                   grant,
                   o_count, 
                   o_shift_base1,
                   clk );

parameter WIDTH = 8;
parameter count_WIDTH = 3;

input  [WIDTH-1:0] req;     //input byte to enable which bits to count through
output [WIDTH-1:0] grant;  //output byte to enable which bit has been chosen
output [count_WIDTH-1:0] o_count;
output [WIDTH-1:0] o_shift_base1;
input  clk;

reg [WIDTH-1:0] shift_base1  = 8'b00000001; //bit to shift
wire [2*WIDTH-1:0] double_req = {req,req}; //double reg to accomodate roll over from calculations
wire [2*WIDTH-1:0] double_grant = double_req & ~(double_req- 
shift_base1);//dounle grant to accomdate roll over
reg [count_WIDTH-1:0] count  = 3'b000; //counter to drive shifted bit

always@(posedge clk)
begin

//adjust count via the grant to skip inactive clock cycles so granted value plays for one clock cycle only.
case(grant)
'h01: count = 3'b000; 
'h02: count = 3'b001; 
'h04: count = 3'b010; 
'h08: count = 3'b011; 
'h10: count = 3'b100; 
'h20: count = 3'b101; 
'h40: count = 3'b110; 
'h80: count = 3'b111; 
default: count = count; 
endcase

count = count-1;
shift_base1 = 8'b00000001;
shift_base1 = shift_base1 << count;  //shift bit by count amount.
end

assign grant = double_grant[WIDTH-1:0] | double_grant[2*WIDTH-1:WIDTH]; //concanterate double grant and pass to grant
assign o_count = count;
assign o_shift_base1 = shift_base1;

endmodule
```

Here is the testbench:

```
Heare is the testbench:

`timescale 1ns/1ns //Adjust to suit

module ripple_borrow_tb;  // No ports!
parameter WIDTH = 8;
parameter count_WIDTH = 3;

reg [WIDTH-1:0]req ;
wire [WIDTH-1:0]grant ;
wire [count_WIDTH-1:0]o_count ;
wire [WIDTH-1:0]o_shift_base1 ;
reg clk ;


 ripple_borrow uut (
.req ( req ),
.grant ( grant ),
.o_count ( o_count ),
.o_shift_base1 ( o_shift_base1 ),
.clk ( clk )
);

parameter PERIOD = 10; //adjust for your timescale


initial begin
   $dumpvars(2, ripple_borrow_tb);
   clk = 1'b0;
   #(PERIOD/2);
   forever
   #(PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin 

   req='b11111111;
   #(PERIOD*16);
   req='b01010101;
   #(PERIOD*8);
   req='b00000011;
   #(PERIOD*8);

  $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Here is a simulation of working count up:
[image: Count Up Success]

In this simulation. Everything is working as expected. On every clock cycle Only the active '1s' in the byte are "granted" and they are only active for one clock cycle.
However. When i try to count down. "count = count-1". The granted signal gets stuck and holds on the highest step.

Here is a simulation of the failed count down:
[image]

As you can see. Unless the whole byte is '1'. It gets stuck on the 7 count. My assumption is that by initialising the shift_base1 to '00000001 and then counting backwards to 7 on every clock cycle. It gets stuck in a 0-7-0-7 loop. Its just confusing that it works when the whole byte is active.
Can somebody please tell me why this is going wrong and help me with a solution. Or offer a better solution to my problem. Even something in VHDL.

I have only been using vivado and writing HDL code for a month or two now. I am still trying to understand at the moment. I have designed a few basic counters in VHDL and Verilog. So my knowledge is limited. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have edited the original question so that it contains the code that fails, added the testbench a provided simulations of a successful count up design and the failing count down design. I hope this is enough information.

Comment: There is some poor modeling going on here.  You are going to get unexpected results, in the always@(posedge clk) block.  If you want to model synchronous logic use non-blocking assignments (<=) in the  always@(posedge clk) block.  If you want combinational logic use always@(*) blocks and blocking assignments.  See https://www.nandland.com/articles/blocking-nonblocking-verilog.html and https://class.ece.uw.edu/371/peckol/doc/Always@.pdf for tutorials.  You have blocking assignments (=) in the always@(posedge clk) block which is not good modeling 99.9999 % of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if `req == 3`  then --> `grant = 01` --> `count = 7` --> `shift = 80`  ... There is no aarithmetical way out of this till you change *req*.

As was mentioned in comments, you should have used non-blocking assignments in the code of the flop.

But in coding it, there are at least two mistakes: you use `count` and `shift` both as a temporary variable and as the output of the flop. This is a bad practice.  In general, with temp vars you should use the followint scheme:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
   tmp = some-expression;
   out <= tmp;
end
```

Otherwise it creates confusion.
In case of the counter i think that you meant something different than use a temp var, probably a default value assignment, like

````
always @(posedge clk)  begin
    count <= count - 1;
    case(grant)
       h01: count = 3'b000; 
       ...
     endcase
     ```
````

or maybe using it in default

```
    default: count <= count - 1;
```

BTW, never use expressions like *count = count;* It makes little sense and might cause tool issues.

with the *shift* you really use it as temp. don't. use the literal direclty: `shift_base1 <= 8'b1 << count;` or make a `parameter one=8'b1; ... shift <= shift << one;`

Other suggestions:

Never use initialization of *reg*, *logic*, and other vars at declaration in the modules of DUTs. They might not be synthesizable. (it is ok with *wires*). You should create a proper initialization instead with a reset signal.